How to resolve a React native prototype error from GestureHandler
i have this issue in a React Native project when i try to start my app with Android in ExpoGo.
I have updated the dependencies that were causing some previous errors but this one is still here and i don't know how to resolve it.
Here the screenshot of the error: https://i.sstatic.net/rsuaTZkZ.jpg
Here the console error:
` ERROR  TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined

This error is located at:
    in Pager (created by TabView)
    in RNGestureHandlerRootView (created by GestureHandlerRootView)
    in GestureHandlerRootView (created by TabView)
    in TabView (created by MaterialTopTabView)
    in MaterialTopTabView (created by MaterialTopTabNavigator)
    in MaterialTopTabNavigator (created by HomeTa
    in HomeTab (created by SceneView)
    in StaticContainer
    in EnsureSingleNavigator (created by SceneView)
    in SceneView (created by CardContainer)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by CardContainer)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by CardContainer)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View
    in CardSheet (created by Card)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by Animated(View))
    in Animated(View) (created by PanGestureHandler)
    in PanGestureHandler (created by PanGestureHandler)
    in PanGestureHandler (created by Card)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by Animated(View))
    in Animated(View) (created by Card)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by Card)
    in Card (created by CardContainer)
    in CardContainer (created by CardStack)
    in RNSScreen (created by Animated(Anonymous))
    in Animated(Anonymous) (created by InnerScreen)
    in Suspender (created by Freeze)
    in Suspense (created by Freeze)
    in Freeze (created by DelayedFreeze)
    in DelayedFreeze (created by InnerScreen)
    in InnerScreen (created by Screen)
    in Screen (created by MaybeScreen)
    in MaybeScreen (created by CardStack)
    in RNSScreenContainer (created by ScreenContainer)
    in ScreenContainer (created by MaybeScreenContainer)
    in MaybeScreenContainer (created by CardStack)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by Background)
    in Background (created by CardStack)
    in CardStack (created by HeaderShownContext)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by SafeAreaProviderCompat)
    in SafeAreaProviderCompat (created by StackView)
    in RNGestureHandlerRootView (created by GestureHandlerRootView)
    in GestureHandlerRootView (created by StackView)
    in StackView (created by StackNavigator)
    in PreventRemoveProvider (created by NavigationContent)
    in NavigationContent
    in Unknown (created by StackNavigator)
    in StackNavigator (created by AppNavigator)
    in EnsureSingleNavigator

I have tried to update the GestureHandler but nothing changed
